# Azure Blob Storage not listing blobs

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am with trouble listing blobs from a specific container

I am using the oficial code, in Python, to list:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

account_name = 'xxxx'
account_key = 'xxxx'
container_name = 'yyyyyy'

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, 
account_key=account_key) 

print("\nList blobs in the container")
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
```

I have received the error:

```
raise AzureException(ex.args[0])

AzureException: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

The version of azure storage related packages installed are:

```
azure-mgmt-storage                    2.0.0
azure-storage-blob                    1.4.0
azure-storage-common                  1.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the same code of yours with my account, it works fine without any issue. Then, according to the error information, I also tried to reproduce it, as below.

Test 1. When I tried to run the code `'123'+('A','B')` in Python 3.7, I got the similar issue as the figure below.

[image]

Test 2. When ran the same code in Python 3.6, the error information is different.

[image]

Test 3. When in Python 2 (just on WSL), the same issue is like in Python 3.7

[image]

So I guess you were using Python 3.7 or 2 to run your code, and the issue was caused by using `+` symbol to concat a string with a tuple at other where of your codes. Please try to check carefully or update your post for more details about the debug information includes line number and its codes for helping to analyze.